# Object extract properties

Tags: php, arrays, object, extract

I have an object as this:

```
object(stdClass)#27 (1)
{
    [0] => object(stdClass)#26 (6)
    {
        ["_id"] => object(MongoId)#24 (1)
        {
            ["$id"] => string(24) "4e6ea439caa47c2c0c000000" 
        }
        ["username"] => string(16) "wdfkewkghbrjkghb"
        ["email"]=> string(24) "wdhbfjkwhegerg@â‚¬rg.efg"
        ["password"]=> string(32) "4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93"
        ["slug"]=> string(16) "wdfkewkghbrjkghb"
        ["insert_datetime"]=> string(19) "2011-09-13 12:09:49" 
    } 

}
```

I assign this object to `$user`.

I can't get access on this object properties doing $user->username cause I receive the message:

> Undefined property: `stdClass::$username`

Then if I do `var_dump(get_object_vars($user))` it returns an empty array.

How do I grab the properties? I don't want to use loops if I can avoid it.

---

The process is this:

1. Retrieve results from mongo_db:

   ```
   $returns = array();

   while ($documents->hasNext())
   {
       if ($this->CI->config->item('mongo_return') == 'object')
       {
           $returns[] = (object) $documents->getNext();    
       }

       if ($this->CI->config->item('mongo_return') == 'array')
       {
           $returns[] = (array) $documents->getNext();
       }
   }

   if ($this->CI->config->item('mongo_return') == 'object')
   {
       return (object)$returns;
   }


   if ($this->CI->config->item('mongo_return') == 'array')
   {
       return $returns;
   }
   ```
2. passing data to model

   ```
   function populateBy($what = false) {
       return $this->mongo_db
                   ->where($what)
                   ->get($this->tb['users']);
   }
   ```
3. definitely grab results in controller:

   ```
   $what = array(
       'email'=>$email,
       'password'=>$password,
       'confirm'=>'1'
   );

   $user  = $this->model_user->populateBy($what);
   ```

Comment: Could you show me the context. I think i can answer your question but i would like to see your thought process first

Comment: @gilden: That was the right answer; why did you delete it?

Comment: @tomalak-geretkal I did some investigating and I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: i checked out in time (before he deleted it) the gilden's answer and i proved echo $user[0]->username; but it's not correct :P , it returns error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @gilden: Well, your answer was correct but incomplete. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As gilden says, the property you're looking for is a property of a *subobject*. However, he missed that object property access is not the same as array element access.

The real problem you're facing here is that you've converted an array to object, and now you have a numeric property name. To get to properties you have to use syntax like `$user->0->username`, but clearly this is not valid as `0` is not a valid variable name.

From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: **integer properties are
>   unaccessible** *[sic]*; private variables have the class name prepended to the
>   variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the
>   variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.
>   This can result in some unexpected behaviour:

The function [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) converts back into an array again so that it *appears* to work, but in fact anything could happen: the behaviour is unspecified because the object elements were rendered inaccessible in the intermediate stage. Similarly, `$user->{'0'}->username` may work for you but I would avoid it.

Unfortunately this means that you'll have to change the way your code works: do not convert a numerically-indexed array to an object.

Answer (score 2):

Your `username` property is not where you're looking for it. Try

```
$username = $user[0]->username;
```

**EDIT** Trying this gives me some unexpected results. I get `"Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"` so what I think you should do is using a `foreach` loop

```
// $users is the object in this sample
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $username = $user->username;
}
```

**EDIT 2** You could use [`get_object_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
$users = get_object_vars($users);
$username = $users[0]->username;
```

Comment: check my question has this line : "i don't want to use loops if possible, thx" :P

Comment: or better if to put loops could be great to put that in model function populateBy(){} and return to controller the object usefull to do $user->username without cycles in controllers i mean :P

Comment: Sorry. I'm investigating it as we speak. It made me curious.

Comment: with EDIT 2 it says: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: what about .. uhm .. at this point .. could be great to count the object arrays, if object contains only 1 array could be great to send from model to the controller a recomposed object with all prroperties so in controller i will be able to just make echo $user->username;   can you help me doing this? :P